# Using IntelliJ IDE to autocomplete line and place semi-colon

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In eclipse you can hit "enter" and the IDE will automatically take you to the end of the line and place a semicolon.

In IntelliJ, if you hit shift-enter you get similar behavior minus adding the semicolon. I have read and tried cntrl-shift-enter and you get the *exact* same behavior. However, that is such an awkward key combination to be using all the time, at least much more so than the one-button approach using Eclipse.

Any ideas?

[IntelliJ autocomplete escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631741/intellij-autocomplete-escape)

Answer (score 22):

In InteiJ IDEA use (Ctrl-Shift-Enter) for "Smart Autocomplete".

It will end the line "smartly" with a semicolon as you wish. It also works in a few different situations like IF statements of FOR loops.

Comment: For Mac-Users it is Cmd-Shift-Enter

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you redo the key binding?

Go to: (spanner icon) Settings -> Keymap -> Complete Current Statement and rebind how you will (for example, ctrl-enter might suit you better).

Or there's also a default keymap set for Eclipse that you can choose. I'm not sure if it affects the complete-current-line action, but you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ctrl+shift+space

Answer (score 0):

if you want always have it just do this

[image]